# remove the cached token from Powershell

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server, access-token

Whenever I connect to Exchange online, it caches my token. So I cannot use another credential for connecting EXO. So could you please advise how to clear this cached token from powershell?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to select the desired account to be used to connect to EXO regardless of the signed-in status displayed on one or more of them. If you want to remove any of them, you can use the 3 dots.

Comment: Please note that my accounts are in on-prem. So I am authenticating via ADFS..

1. 3 dot is not working for me. If I click on signout and forget and same cached cred appears when I connect next time... 
2. If I "use another account", then it uses the cached cred without prompting for new cred..

Comment: Hello, apologies for the delay in my response. You need to [create an Azure Support Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) ensuring [Advanced diagnostic collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request#advanced-diagnostic-information-logs) is enabled and request it to be assigned to Alfredo Revilla (that's me), come back and let me know.